# TomorrowLand global journey from London to Brussels. Visa for Belgium or France?

Tags: visas, schengen, pakistani-citizens

I will be travelling for TomorrowLand on their global journey from London to the Brussels train station, but I'm confused whether to get the visa for Belgium or France. I have a Pakistani passport, so I need the visa.

Answer (score 2):

Your travel through France will be much shorter than your stay in Belgium.

You need to apply for the main destination if there is one, and I would say Belgium is the main destination in this case.

Comment: My main destination is Belgium and then back after staying 5 days there to London on the same train from Brussels to London.